# MySQL Error: This version doesn't support multiple triggers

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

I created a table called "BranchTest". My objective is that anytime I insert a record where BranchNo = 'B005', then the address needs to be '123 Main St.' I created the following trigger, but keep getting this "doesn't support multiple triggers" error. Any solution that can fix this? I apologize for the formatting, if someone could please assist in this as well. I'm new to this.

```
CREATE TRIGGER AddressUpdate
AFTER INSERT ON branchtest 
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF (NEW.branchno='B005')
    THEN 
        INSERT INTO Address(address) 
        VALUES ('123 Main St');
    END IF;
END;
```

Comment: It seems like you already have an after insert trigger defined for that table. Could you please check this? Maybe you can extend the existing trigger by your insert here.

Comment: You can check if you already have triggers on this table: `SHOW TRIGGERS LIKE 'branchtest'\G` in the MySQL client.